# Wordpress: Add content to edit.php

Tags: wordpress

[image]I'm trying to find out what action hook/filter I can use to insert content on the admin "edit.php" page (i want to place a few links above the 'posts' table)? I've found "edit_form_after_title" and "edit_form_after_editor" (these do exactly what I want to do, but they are for posts.php, not edit.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just wanted to add to the post title link you could do something like this

```
if (is_admin()) {
    add_filter('the_title', function($title) {
        return $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    });
}
```

however, it doesn't sound like you want to add text to the title link.

To add html after the title and before the actions links, you could do like this

```
if (is_admin()) {
    add_filter('post_row_actions', function($args) {
        // echo your custom content here
        return $args; // and dont forget to return the actions
    });
}
```

There is also `page_row_actions` for the page edit screen (`post_row_actions` is only for posts)

As far as adding stuff before the title, I don't see a hook/filter to do that. See `wp-admin/class-wp-posts-list-table.php` line 463 `function single_row` if you want to look for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I added a screenshot to show you what I'm looking for. I'll check out those pages!

Comment: @Rob - where you have `// echo your custom content here` - this echos text in each row/post in the list. I don't think this is what OP was asking.

Answer (score 8):

With the help of this answer: [How do you create a custom edit.php / edit pages page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115164/59816)

I came up with this:

```
<?php
# Called only in /wp-admin/edit.php pages
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() {
  add_filter( 'views_edit-talk', 'talk_tabs' ); // talk is my custom post type
});

# echo the tabs
function talk_tabs() {
 echo '
  <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
    <a class="nav-tab" href="admin.php?page=guests">Profiles</a>
    <a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="edit.php?post_type=talk">Talks</a>
    <a class="nav-tab" href="edit.php?post_type=offer">Offers</a>
  </h2>
 ';
}
?>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: perfect answer thanks! any idea how to do it for taxonomy pages with edit-tags.php?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242633/editing-edit-tags-php-page-in-wp-admin

Comment: This is awesome, took quite a bit of google'ing to find this.

Comment: This code worked for me, but replaces the status nav with whatever is echo'ed in `talk_tabs`. I was able to leave the status nav as is AND add text above it by echoing the additional text, and then returning what was passed to the filter to begin with - satisfying OP's initial request. Here's the code to do that: ```function talk_tabs ($pre_filter_content) {
   echo '<p>Some additional text at the top of the page</p>';
   return $pre_filter_content;
  }```